# STK4192II pinout?

Tags: schematics, reverse-engineering, pinout

I have been blowing through bandwidth trying to find a pinout diagram of an old STK4192II stereo amp IC but all I can find are [reference design schematics](http://kravitnik.narod.ru/dtsheet/amplifier/STK4192.pdf), while these will work I guess I want to use this as learning project on the effects of caps and resistors on sound while also making a 5.1 ch amp for my computer (the computer will be the Dolby processor).

So has anyone come across that? Or does anyone have tips on reverse engineering the pinouts (is that even practical?)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Cension! I've done minor edits to your question just so it follows the site standards closer. I took the liberty of adding an schematic I found. I hope it is not incorrect. But didn't find the pinout descriptions just like you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching much longer than I expected to search for this, I have come to the conclusion that this does not exist.  You could easily reverse engineer it by using the reference design schematics, specifically the Sample Application Circuit diagram and the table of description of external components diagram.  You may need to infer some names to put along with it but it would be helpful nonetheless.

There seems to be a nice opportunity for you here then if you would be willing to make a pinout diagram of it.  If you did that and then posted your project online, you would recieve all the traffic relating to people looking for the exact same thing.

Comment: Lol I hear ya, thankfully I just found the old board I ripped them from so now all I have to do is run a bypass through the Dobly chip